# Help creating a team site survey

Tags: list, survey

I am in over my head a bit in terms of SharePoint 2013. I've never worked with it before and I was volunteered to help design a new team site.

So, I have about a week to create a form (survey?) that allows folks to input problems and resolutions that show on the main page of a team site, and sorts them by frequency. I need it to show the data graphically. I also need it to email out the top five results at the end of the night and then purge. Is this even doable?

Sorry if this is the incorrect place to post. Any help at all would be amazing.

Comment: Cassie isn't clever :).. Do you know how to code? or use Visual Studio.. How does the frequency calculated, is it system calculated or a person updates the frequency?

Comment: I imagine it would be based on keywords, or even based on how many 'likes' a submission has. My knowledge of code is severely lacking, I've come to realize. So, my idea was that person A says 'we are getting a lot of calls about system B not functioning; my resolution was to blah' and then if everyone was having this problem they would 'like' the submission, and it could be sorted that way, or input a different problem/solution if it varied from the first post. I hope I make sense with this...

Comment: I have visual studio, but have not used it much.

Answer (score 0):

Well now is the time you make use of it.. Input problems and resolutions can be simply done in a Custom List with these columns (if you don't want anything fancy), OOB list forms will generate those forms..

However for the like button, I would suggest you make a [Custom Ribbon Buttom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630938%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and write your custom code to manage likes.. Maybe another list saving all the likes with people column to identify who liked it (you don't want the same guy like again n again right?).. This list should have a lookup column to the first list. You can use JSOM to look into the people list, if the like isn't there for the current logged in user, you add a like for him.. The good thing about lookup column is that it will give you a [Lookup Count Column](http://pawansatope.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html) which you can use in your first list to determine the frequency of likes..

Now about graphical representation, you might need to look at the [Chart Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-the-chart-web-part-HA101889216.aspx) and [How to: Use Chart Web Part](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Chart-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx) (only available in Enterprise Edition)

Finally about the notification emails popping each night, you will need to [write a custom Timer Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh528519%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and schedule it to run every night.. In that you will get the list and query it to get the top 5 items ordered by the Lookup count column.. Construct a fancy email and send it to the desired people..

Try these things and if you get stuck, post another specific question..